# What does it mean when my wireless lan is "hard blocked"?

Tags: wifi, hardware

I am attempting to setup wifi on my beaglebone.

```
root@beaglebone:~# rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

unblock does nothing:

```
root@beaglebone:~# rfkill unblock all
root@beaglebone:~# rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
root@beaglebone:~#
```

FYI:  My beaglebone is connected and powered via USB from my computer.

Answer (score 3):

You usually have a button or switch on your wifi adapter which can be used to forcibly stop the signal. There is nothing you can do in software to change that, only observe it (but note that there are some drivers which do not observe it correctly, and always generate one result); you need to press the button or flip the switch.

Comment: I will look into this regarding the beaglebone itself.  I pretty much don't see a switch on the wifi adapter but will also look closer when I get back home.